# In the visualization of fft using glsl, rewrite from glsl 120 to 150

Tags: c++, glsl, shader, fft, openframeworks

I am trying to make fft texture using GLSL.
However, although it was created in the current version 150, thought that I wanted to rewrite it to version 120, it does not work well,
I will paste the source code below, so please let me know if you know what is the cause. I am delighted.

glsl150.vert

```
#version 150
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
in vec4 position;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec2 vTexCoord;

void main(){
    vTexCoord = texcoord;
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

glsl150.frag

```
#version 150

uniform sampler2DRect tex;
uniform float rawFft[256];
in vec2 vTexCoord;

out vec4 outputColor;

void main(){

    if (vTexCoord.y < 1.0) {
        int i = int(vTexCoord.x);
        outputColor.r = rawFft[i];
    } else {
        vec2 st = vTexCoord;
        st.y -= 1.0;
        outputColor.r = texture(tex, st).r;
    }
    outputColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

**GLSL150 FFT Texture:**

[image: img]

glsl120.vert

```
#version 120
#extension GL_ARB_texture_rectangle : enable

void main(){
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = gl_Vertex;
}
```

glsl120.frag

```
#version 120
#extension GL_ARB_texture_rectangle : enable

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform float rawFft[256];

vec4 outputColor;

void main(){

    if (gl_TexCoord[0].y < 1.0) {
        int i = int(gl_TexCoord[0].x);
        outputColor.r = rawFft[i];
    } else {
        vec2 st = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
        st.y -= 1.0;
        outputColor.r = texture2D(tex, st).r;
    }
    outputColor.a = 1.0;

    gl_FragColor = outputColor;
}
```

**GLSL120 FFT Texture:**

[image: img]

I want to make the result which is out in 150 work even with 120.
What is wrong?

Comment: I tried `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex` but it was useless.

Comment: OP suggest 150 -> 120 and title 120 -> 150 so which one is it ?